# Pandas DataFrame columns getting passed to the new data dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new dataframe using existing dataframe values. Below code accepts a dataframe called dfhiddencols, which has 3 columns in it

> Parent , Childlist, Formula

[image: dfhiddencols]

then it creates a new dataframe called newdf with 2 columns called

> Parent, Child

then it loops through each row of dfhiddencols to find a particular pattern. when it finds the pattern, it adds a new row to dfnew. by fetching parent column value from dfhiddencols and matched pattern string.

However, when this new record is added its adding 2 additional columns to newdf

> childlist, formula

These 2 columns are not defined when creating the dictionary createrow. **Do you know why the columns are getting passed to the new dataframe and how to avoid such scenario?**

```
def extracthiddencolumns(dfhiddencols):
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['child', 'parent'])
createrow ={}
for idx, row in dfhiddencols.iterrows():
    #if len(str(row['formula'])) > 3:
        for formula in row['formula'].split('|||'):
            if formula != '' and '??' in formula:
                formula = formula.strip('\n')
                formula = formula.strip('\t')
                for i in re.findall(r"\[\?\?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\?\?\]", formula):
                    strconcat = i[0] + "." + i[1]
                    parent = row['parent']
                    createrow = {'child': parent, 'parent': strconcat}
                    newdf = dfhiddencols.append(createrow, ignore_index=True)
            createrow = {}
newdf.drop(columns=['childlist', 'formula'])
return newdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a for loop is not a good idea, but in your code, you can try this to append each row to `newdf`:

```
#all your code up to below
createrow = {'child': parent, 'parent': strconcat}
newdf = newdf.append(pd.DataFrame(createrow), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, it's still creating those additional 2 columns. not sure why.

Comment: If you could add a sample dataframe of your real data, I'm sure there would be a more concise and pandaic way to get your desired result. Because writing so many for loops in pandas is definitely not something that pandas is created for!

Comment: I have added the image with hidden data and structure

Comment: I meant something like `df.head(10).to_dict(orient='list')` . And then you can copy this into your question, and also specify what is your expected output.

Comment: the image is showing df.head(5), what else do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Its embarrassing to say, I was appending new record to the passed DF, hence it explains new columns showing up in the dataframe